# When do you need a new class in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, pdf

I am just learning objective c and xcode. I love the interface building, but as far as the coding goes, I'm a little lost.

Basically, I am trying to understand when I need a new class. I am reading a book that covers the "how-to" really well, but not the "why."

I am building an application and I have the interface pretty much complete.

In other words, I have a lot of NSObjects floating around but, unfortunately, these objects don't know how to communicate with each other or with the underlying program. Here's the hypothetical.

I have several text fields that will eventually communicate their input to tables within my interface and also external PDF templates.

My basic understanding of Obj. C and Xcode is that in order for the text field to communicate it's contents to either the PDF file or the table, I will need to create a new class to specify the text field's contents as a variable, and to send that variable somewhere (PDF or table).

However, if I have a button that will ultimately be responsible for sending the textfield's data somewhere, I will also need to make a connection between the button and the text field, like this.

(button) --- fetches ---> (text field contents) ---sends to ---> (table)

So, up this point, I would be including all of this in one class, right? With the text field input as a variable that I declare in my header file, the button's method/action which I include in the header file and implement in the .m file, and the table which would also be declared in both .h. and .m files?

Am I on the right track? Also, this is just one connection from one text field. If I decided to this with more text fields in the application, would I have to create a separate class for each? Or could I use the same class and distinguish them by id's?

I am clearly a noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the piece of the puzzle that you're missing is design patterns. The docs that you've read provide the *how* - how to create classes, add methods, etc. That's like learning preparation techniques in a cooking class. How to chop, blend, dice, marinate, etc. Design patterns are the higher-level recipes that show you how to put it all together, using the techniques you've learned to assemble the ingredients into a finished meal.

To get started, have a look at the Design Patterns section in Apple's own [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Comment: I would add that while you should read about design patterns , don't expect that it will make 100% sense yet. Build some apps and as you go along, you'll run into design problems like: "How do I get this data I pulled from this URL into this view controller over here." I feel like until you've actually encountered the problem, the solution (the design pattern) is devoid of real context and will have limited meaning for you. Basically, I think building stuff is the best way to learn, just make sure you rely on good sources for help. Unlearning bad habits is much harder than building good ones.